# Working on fixing perms for my Discord bot

Tags: discord, discord.js

I am currently working on Discord bot. I have a line of code that makes it so that only a certain rank can use it, and I would like to make it so that instead of only 1 rank being able to use the command, any role that has an admin rank can. My code:

```
bot.on('message', message => {

    let args = message.content.substring(config.prefix.length).split(" ");

    switch (args[0]) {
        case 'kick':
            if (!args[1]) message.channel.send("No person included.")

            const user = message.mentions.users.first();

            if (user) {
                const member = message.guild.member(user);

                if (member) {
                    member.kick('You were kicked.').then(() => {
                        message.reply(`Sucessfully kicked @${user.tag}.`);
                    }).catch(err => {
                        message.reply(`I can\'t kick the member. (perms?)`);
                        console.log(err);
                    });
                } else {
                    message.reply("That user isn\`t in this server!");
                }
            }
            break;
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

To make it that only those with an admin role and use the command, you can just put this code at the top:

```
if(!message.member.roles.cache.has('InsertAdminRoleID')) return
```

This way, only those who has the admin role can use this command.

Comment: Not as the role, but the admin permission.

Comment: Then try something like `if(!message.author.hasPermission('ADMINISTRATOR`)) return;`

Not too sure whether this is outdated or not, hope it works for you :)

Comment: Sorry, try doing `if(!message.author.hasPermission(['ADMINISTRATOR']))` instead.

Comment: hasPermission is not a function.

Comment: maybe try switching out 'author' for 'member' instead?